# Fastest way to find/add missing rows (50K+)

Tags: mysql, select, rows

I have a Mysql table (innodb) with exactly 50M rows (yep, 50 million rows, not more or less) with the following columns:

- 'ai' -> Auto increment, unsigned bigint;
- 'client_id' -> unique key, unsigned bigint;
- 'has_dog' -> bool;
- eventually more to come...

Let's asume:
I want to send all clients that have a dog a gift. With a simple query I can find all dog owners, but...
But what if some rows are missing? Maybe deleted? Maybe not inserted at all?
When I search for COUNT(client_id), I expect exactly 50,000,000 rows, but the result is less, unfortunately.

Question:
With 10 rows, it's easy to see what rows are missing, but how do I know which rows are missing with 50M rows?

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with your select query not the data? Can you post your select query?

Comment: What criteria do you use to determine that there is a row missing?